# The last score point does not increase/increment in a quiz app

Tags: ios, swift

Say, I have got a multiple choice test, which consists of 5 questions. When the answer is correct, guestion number, score points, progress bar (still in the future, now it’s not functioning yet) should be reloaded, i.e. increased by one point.

The problem is that when the last question is answered correctly (the 5th question) and an alert controller shows up, the score point doesn’t increase to 5, but remains at 4. I was trying to put it (score +=1) in all different spots of this function *private func checkAnswer(for answer: Answer)* to make the score increase to 5, but useless.

It probably will work by introducing *@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton)*,
but in that case a lot of stuff should be rewritten.

So my question is whether it is possible make it work in the existing code.

```
`private func shuffleQuestions() {
  shuffledQuestions = questions.shuffled()
  questionNumber = 1
  score = 0
  showQuestion()
}

private func showQuestion() {

  questionCounterLabel.text = "\(questionNumber)/\(questions.count)"
  scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
  progressView.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(questions.count))*CGFloat(questionNumber)
  
  currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[questionNumber - 1]
  questionNameLabel.text = currentQuestion?.text ?? ""
  
  questionNumberLabel.text = "Question \(questionNumber)"
  questionNumber += 1
  score += 1
  tableView.reloadData()
  
}

private func checkAnswer(for answer: Answer) {
  
  if answer.correct {
    if questionNumber > questions.count {
      
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                          message: "End of Quiz. Do you want to start over?",
                                          preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart",
                                              style: .default,
                                              handler: { action in
                                              self.shuffleQuestions() } )
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      return
    }
    showQuestion()
  } else {
    // wrong
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong",
                                  message: "You failed",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss",
                                  style: .cancel,
                                  handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true)
  }
}`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is the last question and the answer is correct bump score and assign it to the label:

```
if questionNumber > questions.count {
            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                          message: "End of Quiz. Do you want to start over?",
                                          preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart",
                                              style: .default,
                                              handler: { action in
                                              self.shuffleQuestions() } )
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      return
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, burnsi! It really helped. ) The only thing is that if you add both two lines that you suggested, then the final score gets incremented by 2, i. e. from 4 to 6. But if you don't bump the score and just add the second line `scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"`, then the score goes up by 1 (from 4 to 5). But I still cannot figure it out why it is so. )